# python possible indentation error? don't know what's gone wrong?

Tags: python, syntax-error

I'm having some issues with my program just as soon as I had completed it. I don't really see much wrong with it but I get an error saying that "while" is a syntax error.

```
pass1 = raw_input("Please enter a password(Must contain a number,at least 1 capital 

letter and must be longer that 6 characters): ")
time.sleep(1)
pass2 = raw_input("Please re-enter your password: ")
updown = any(map(str(isupper, pass1))
while not pass1 or not pass1 == pass2 or not num_there(pass1) == True or len(pass1) < 6:
    if updown == False:
        print "\n Your password is not accepted!"
        pass1 = raw_input("Please enter a password(Must contain a number,at least 1 capital letter and must be longer that 6 characters): ")
        time.sleep(1)
        pass2 = raw_input("Please re-enter your password: ")
    else:
        continue
else:
    print "Password accepted!"
    f.write(pass1)
```

Comment: Not enough close parens on the line before the `while`.

Comment: Change `any(map(str(isupper, pass1))` to `any(map(str(isupper, pass1)))`

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a closing parenthesis:

```
updown = any(map(str(isupper, pass1))
#           ^   ^   ^              ^^?
#            \   \   \------------///
#             \   ----------------//
#              --------------------
```

Fix the problem by adding that missing third `)`:

```
updown = any(map(str(isupper, pass1)))
```

Python allows for logical lines to implicitly span multiple physical lines, provided you surround the expression in parentheses or brackets or braces.

But that also means that if you are missing the closing parenthesis, Python doesn't find out there is a problem with the expression until the next line.

So, rule of thumb, if you get a syntax error in Python that doesn't immediately make sense, look at the lines *before* and count your brackets.

However, in this case you actually added an opening parentheses where you should have used a `.`. The expression tried to use should really be:

```
updown = any(map(str.isupper, pass1))
```

Comment: However now I am getting an error saying isupper isn't defined?

Comment: @user3054652: probably because you meant to use `any(map(str.isupper, pass1))` instead?